# Why there is not initial position term in SUVAT equations?

Tags: calculus, kinematics

Just a quick question.
From calculus I know that $s(t)=s_{0}+v_{0}t+\frac{1}{2}at^{2}$ but the initial position term, $s_{0}$, has disappeared from SUVAT formulas.

Why?

Is it always assumed that $s_{0}=0$?

Comment: Your observation is correct. If you are used to seeing $s = ut + 1/2at^2$, that's assuming the object's initial position is the origin.

Comment: Does that mean that these formulas cannot be used in, say, free-fall problems when the object is released form a given heigh?

Comment: You can, but just take care to consider this in your final answer so it makes sense. Better still: use the formula you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you always take s0 = 0 in problems , fore example going from place A to C , but there is a point B , where maybe velocity is changing or something happens ... Mostly you divide the pathing in 2 distances AB and BC always starting from the specifc origin , so s0=0